# Highcharts two series, each is stacked area

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to make a chart where there is a total of 3 series, and 2 of those 3 are stacked with the third one.
In the example, the red and green charts are both stacked with the blue one.
Any way of doing it?

[image: chart]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a solution, here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/WCmGC/

```
series: [
    // first stack 
     {
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [30, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4],
        stack: 0,
        name: 'pos pos'
    },
    {
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
        stack: 0,
        name: 'neu pos'
    }, 
    // second stack 
    {
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [148.5, 216.4, 30, 176.0, 135.6],
        stack: 1,
        name: 'neu neg'
    },
    {
        type: 'areaspline',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0],
        stack: 1,
        name: 'neu neg'
    }]
```